# Image moving across screen at the Speed of Light

Tags: image

Would it be possible to write a program that can make an image, lets say a circle the size of a dime, move across your computer screen back and forth at the speed of light having a monitor that is lets say 20 inches wide; if not, then would it be possible to make the image move across the screen at 50 or 100 mph??

Comment: Do you know the refresh rate of your monitor?  Do you know how far light travels in one refresh blink?  Do the math first, then post that result in your question.  Hint.  In 1/60th of a second, light (in a vacuum) goes several kilometers.  How many?

Comment: You will be limited to the refresh rate. For an object moving at the speed of light across the screen you can just tell the user that you are doing it. This comment has a marquee at the end of it moving at the speed of light btw.

Comment: Only if your image is made of neutrinos.

Comment: Calculate the speed using the monitor width in pixels and the number of pixels per inch. From that, you get the full monitor width in inches, and then you can figure out the fractional seconds for traveling that distance.

Comment: I like meters! I'm so sorry, but I could not resist :)

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It is not a very important question but I can imagine the OP's curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it be possible to write a program that can make an image, lets say a circle the size of a dime, move across your computer screen back and forth at the speed of light having a monitor that is lets say 20 inches wide

The speed of light is 299,792,458 meters per second. Your screen is about half a meter across, and refreshes about 60 times a second. In a single refresh of the screen, your dime would've had to have crossed the screen five million times.

You can simulate this, though. Just draw a dime-height horizontal bar across the screen.

50 mph is 22.352 meters per second, so you're not going to see anything particularly useful at that speed either.

Comment: What if we had a GIANT monitor?  I wonder how wide the monitor would have to be or how slow the dime would have to move in order to be able to see it going back and forth on the screen if the screen was lets say a mile wide. Time to bring out the calculator!

Comment: @JuanVelez: A mile wide screen?  It would go back and forth 186282 times a second.  Or, 3104 times per frame.  Still a bar.  To see it your screen would have to be over 1034 miles wide.

Comment: @JuanVelez Are you *going* anywhere with this question, or are you just wasting everyone's time with silly hypotheticals? If you're just looking for a conceptualization of how fast light moves, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Speed_of_light_from_Earth_to_Moon.gif

Comment: It may intrest you all that the effect @JuanVelez is after has been observed in nature. The catch: it takes an exploding galaxy at the other side of the universe.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion

Comment: Thank you all for all your responses and discussion. Thanks for the links to the articles as well. They were very interesting and informative.

Answer (score 4):

The speed of light is approximately 186,282 miles per second, which is 11,802,827,520 inches per second. On your 20 inch monitor it would bounce back and forth 590,141,376 times per second. We'll be generous and say that the refresh rate of your monitor is 120 Hz, meaning you'd only be seeing 1 out of every 4,917,845 bounces. This is if the dot could be drawn instantaneously as it was needed.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't not be possible since real speed of light is hardly acheived by anything at all. Even considering a perfect screen working only with optic wire, you would still have to at least travel a distance from the computer to the screen to make and object moving. That signal would travel a distance requiring time and thus, would reduce the overall speed at which your object is traveling on the screen.

50 to 100 mph is absolutely not comparable to the speed of light. It should pose no problem to do so.

Comment: The "travel distance" (cable length) between monitor is not relevant. It means that the animation is shown later than your computer sends it, it does not change the perceived speed of objects moving on screen.

Comment: I did consider traveling the object from a point on the screen to the oposite point on the screen and calculating the time it requires. To simulate such speed interlacing the movement would not be required.